How to remove emails addresses from Recents iOS Mail to which I have sent emails together
I am trying to reduce the number of email addresses in Recents list of the iOS Mail app. Let's say there is an email address, for example user@example.org, such that I have only sent emails to that address only (without having other recipients in these messages). I can remove it by starting to compose a new email, then typing user, and whenever the email address in question appears in the auctocomplete, i can click on the i after the address, and then there is Remove From Recents on the bottom.
However, if I have never sent email just to user@example.org, but always to that address and to anotheruser@example.com, then doing the same procedure does not result in having i after the email address, but instead having user@example.org & anotheruser@example.com, and then > sign after that. Clicking on the >, expands the list of 2 addresses, but when I click on the i after either of them, there is no Remove From Recents on the bottom.
None of these addresses is associated with any contact in the Contacts app. The email addresses are not synced with anything.
So how can I remove emails addresses from the Recents list in iOS Mail to which I have only sent emails together with another address?

Are you using icloud? If you turn off siri suggestions, do the email addresses still appear? https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/about-siri-suggestions-iph6f94af287/ios
Perhaps these are contacts that apple has synced to icloud.
https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/10y2r3s/a_guide_for_deleting_recent_contacts_from_icloud/

Syncing is what I thought about, but the contacts are not synced anywhere (and if they were somehow synced, all contacts would be synced and would have the same problem, however the issue exists only for "paired" contacts). Siri is disabled.

First, open the mail app and tap the Compose New button. Type the email address you want to remove and click the Info button next to it. Tap Remove From Contacts to remove it.

As mentioned in my question, this only works when the email address was used alone when sending emails. It doesn't work when that email address was always used together with another email addresses as recipients.

Did you ask Apple for help here?
